# How to loop sklearn linear regression by values within a column - python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am relatively new to python and programming in general.

I have a csv with three columns, an identifier, distance, and date. The data looks something like:

```
id, date, distance

1, 1850, 150
1, 1950, 200
1, 1990, 250
2, 1850, 130
2, 1950, 180
2, 1990, 210
3, 1850, 200
3, 1950, 220
3, 1990, 250
```

etc...

I'm trying to use sklearn.linear_model LinearRegression. To run a regression on each of these series. 
So I need to basically separate the columns by id. I want a separate result for each group of id's (1, 2, 3, etc).

I was able to do this easily with R by using:

```
reg1 <- lmList(distance ~ date | id, mydata)
```

However, for several reasons, I need to do this with python.

I've imported the csv using pandas.read_csv. Then I assumed I need to attribute each of these to a variable:

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv(location, sep = ",", header = 0)
x = dataset['date']
y = dataset['distance']
z = dataset['id']
```

Then apparently to use them in LinearRegression() and model.fit(x,y) I needed to use

```
x2 = numpy.array(x).T and
y2 = numpy.array(x).T
```

So now that that is all set up, what should I do to actually loop the regression through those id values?

when I try:

```
for n in main_reg2.id:
    model1 = LinearRegression()
    model1.fit(xT1,yT)
    print(model1.coef_, model1.intercept_)
    break
```

It just gives me one result for the whole dataset. And I'm not sure where to tell it to go through the id values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the mixing of jargon, I've had to dabble in 5 different programming and statistical languages over the past 2 years of grad school and am very confused sometimes.

Perhaps I'm overthinking this, or maybe there is some way towards the beginning that I can separate the data?

Also, how would I create a table from this that lists the coefficients and intercepts and whatnot.

Thanks

Updated code so far:
    with open(r'file_location','rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        headers = reader.next()
        for fields in reader:
            your_list = list(reader)

```
z = [_[0] for _ in your_list]
x = [_[1] for _ in your_list]
y = [_[2] for _ in your_list]

id_max = max(z)
new_list = [[]]
for _ in range(id_max):
    new_list.append([])

for index in range(len(z)):
    id = z[index]
    new_entry = [x[index],y[index]]
    print "Adding to index", id, new_entry
    new_list[id].append(new_entry)
print new_list
```

I used header = reader.next() code to get rid of the headers. When I was doing the max(z) before, the header was coming up as the max...

Going through line by line:
I get...

```
id_max = max(z)
print(id_max)
999
```

Which I already know is wrong since the max is 1576.

But moving on.... after the append I get

```
Type Error: range() integer end argument expected, got str
```

Which I don't understand since z is a list of integers from 1 to 1576.

Some examples of the indexes are:

```
z[1] = '10'
y[1] = '2011'
x[1] = '515.8938'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply separate the data by ID at the very start: make this a list of lists:

```
data_list = [
    [1, 1850, 150],
    [1, 1950, 200],
    [1, 1990, 250],
    [2, 1850, 130],
    [2, 1950, 180],
    [2, 1990, 210],
    [3, 1850, 200],
    [3, 1950, 220],
    [3, 1990, 250]
]

z = [_[0] for _ in data_list]
x = [_[1] for _ in data_list]
y = [_[2] for _ in data_list]

# Create a list of empty lists, one for each ID
id_max = max(z)
new_list = [[]]
for _ in range(id_max):
    new_list.append([])

# For each row, add the data to the sub-list for the row ID;
#   ID 0 is not used.
for index in range(len(z)):
    id = z[index]
    new_entry = [x[index], y[index]]
    print "Adding to index", id, new_entry
    new_list[id].append(new_entry)

print new_list
```

new_list is now a list of lists, each sub-list having rows that share the same id.  There are more "Pythonic" ways to do some of these things, but I kept the code to where I expect you can follow the logic.

Output, complete with trace:

```
Adding to index 1 [1850, 150]
[[], [[1850, 150]], [], []]
Adding to index 1 [1950, 200]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200]], [], []]
Adding to index 1 [1990, 250]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [], []]
Adding to index 2 [1850, 130]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [[1850, 130]], []]
Adding to index 2 [1950, 180]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [[1850, 130], [1950, 180]], []]
Adding to index 2 [1990, 210]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [[1850, 130], [1950, 180], [1990, 210]], []]
Adding to index 3 [1850, 200]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [[1850, 130], [1950, 180], [1990, 210]], [[1850, 200]]]
Adding to index 3 [1950, 220]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [[1850, 130], [1950, 180], [1990, 210]], [[1850, 200], [1950, 220]]]
Adding to index 3 [1990, 250]
[[], [[1850, 150], [1950, 200], [1990, 250]], [[1850, 130], [1950, 180], [1990, 210]], [[1850, 200], [1950, 220], [1990, 250]]]
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for responding so quickly. I'm going to walk through this step by step.

First, id_max returns:

2011 

new_list returns:

an empty list the same length as the number in id_max

After that id returns the same number (2011) as id_max

new_entry returns [515.89, 10]

and

new_list[id}.append(new_entry) returns:

IndexError: list of indexes out of range

So I assume the indexes are not the same length and can't be appended?

Edit, sorry: I keep hitting enter to change lines but it keeps saving my edits and this paragraph doesn't seem to be formatted...

Comment: Please do so.  The logic in my head is correct, put I'm not sure I've properly handled the PANDAS structures.

Comment: I'll try this again.

First, id_max returns:

"2011"... 

new_list returns an empty list the same length as the number in id_max. 

After that, id returns the same number (2011) as id_max. 

new_entry returns [515.89, 10]

and

new_list[id}.append(new_entry) returns:

"IndexError: list of indexes out of range". 

So I assume the indexes are not the same length and can't be appended?  


Edit, sorry: I keep hitting enter to change lines but it keeps saving my edits and this paragraph doesn't seem to be formatted...

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well and get the same error message. So... id_max = 1576. id = 1576 and id size = 1. Size of x,y, and z = 6170. The length of new_list = 1576. new_entry gives me [1859,500.16...] but it only has a size of 2 and length of 1..... When I try new_list[1], I get a list that is 6166 in length... I should be only getting those four dates associated with id = 1, not all the dates. ... Indexing works when I manually try x[1], y[1], z[1] I get the values for the first row, which is correct.... So it seems appending them together with is where it is failing. Does that make sense?

Comment: I deleted the unhelpful comments and tested the solution.  I had a problem in Python references.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten back to this. I appreciate the help. When I get a chance to test this again, I'll be sure to mark this answer correct (or not). Thanks

Comment: Ok, so it seems these things are having trouble with the values in the list. When I run the code block starting with "id_max = max(z)" it says... range() integer end argument expected, got str.... So for now, I just changed the max(z) to a number that I know is the max (1567). And that worked. Then I ran the last block and got a similar error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str". So it must not like the list.

Comment: Can you update this with your code and the full error message?  Also, stick in a print statement that displays the index just before we get the error.  I can't debug this from what you've given me, because our mutual point of reference -- the code I posted -- has only integers in the input data and resulting references.  The only indices in my code are "index", which is an integer from a "range" generator; and "id", which is pulled from a list of integers.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, yeah I didn't even think about that. My source data does not include just integers. The first column is id: which are integers... second is distance: which are decimal... and third, date: integers. I'll update the code up at the beginning so you can see it in the correct format.

Comment: Also include the full error message and that print statement I asked about -- let's see the blasted string!  :-)

Comment: Updated above. Does that help?

Comment: Very much.  z is _not_ a list of integers: it's a list of strings that happen to _look_ a lot like integers to us mere mortals.  You didn't give the entire message, I think: there should be location information.  Wherever that came from, convert your value to integer first.  I suspect that it's the id_max, which means that you have to convert the entire list to integers first:  /// z = [int(i) for i in z] ///  Strings have a different sorting order; '2' > '11', for instance.  Otherwise, you could just use /// id_max = int(max(z))

Comment: Alright, now we're talkin! So now, regarding the regression, would I just say,  
    for index in new_list:
        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(not sure, not sure)
        print(model.coef_, model.intercept_)
        break
...? For formatting, see the first code I gave above...

Comment: I'm glad we got you moving.  I don't know the package you're using, so I can't help much on formatting arguments.  I work with the TrustedAnalytics package.